# Text and Box Center of Page

Tags: css, html, center

I have a box centered regardless of window size and text within it but I can't get it to also center text within the box itself and not just centered across. I originally used line height (ok for single word) but it doesn't work for multuple lines of text.

Please explain how it works.

```
<div id="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/84mHh/

Comment: don't you know `text-align:center;` ?

Comment: Do you want the text in the div centered horizontally, vertically, or both?

Comment: Should have made it clear that the text should be in the middle of the box and not just centered across. Edited the details.

Comment: @Charles, I know this question is pretty old, but if you could please accept one of the answers by pressing the check mark next to it that would be great. Accepting an answer marks this question as answered and also helps the person whose question you accept. Thanks! (If none of the answers solved your problem, don't accept any of them.)

Answer (score 0):

I just use `text-align: center;` property

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align: center;`

```
#box { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    background: #b7d84b;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/84mHh/1/

Comment: Should have made it clear that the text should be in the middle of the box and not just centered across. Edited the details.

Answer (score 0):

Start by centering the text using CSS:

```
#box {
    text-align: center;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Then you can use this to make it centered vertically:

```
#box p {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/mz3mx/)**